# When is most of maintenance data collected

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

During which phase of flight is most of the maintenance data collected? Ascend, cruising or descend? Is there a website where I can find such information?

Comment: Aren't data monitored from engine start to engine stop?

Comment: Yes. But when is the main/critical maintenance data collected?

Comment: An example of such data might help to understand. I think critical parameters are permanently monitored, e.g. vibrations are continuously monitored, not only when thrust is maximum (takeoff). Or do you mean: During which phase abnormal values do mostly occur?

Comment: Are vibration parameters considered maintenance data? Because you said that they require real-time monitoring and I don't know if they can be considered maintenance data.

Comment: You may want to read [this](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Aircraft_Condition_Monitoring_System_(ACMS)).

Comment: Are you only interested in engine data or other data as well?

Comment: Any data. In fact, the more data I know of, the better.